# Loft on top curved geometry

Tags: vertices

I have been going crazy trying to loft a rounded top on this design. I have traced it with control point splines in Fusion and tried many ways but cannot seem to get it. Is there a way I can do this in blender, keeping in mind I am very very new to blender and don't understand some of the TERMINOLOGY. I know a lot is different from Fusion 360 that I had been working with. I had put arcs with PLANE along path and guide lines but it somehow will not follow the curves with variable widths. This is a 2 piece heart design I will be adding a solid bottom to and make a decorative box IF I can round over the top. Thank you to anybody who can help guide me through this.

John

[image: Design I am working toward]

Comment: you can do that with curve with a taper object to change the radius all along, or just change de curve points radius, see here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fR2-iEUgyVQ then convert to mesh, cut off the bottom half of the mesh, and extrude down

Answer (score 1):

Create a curve that has the (half) heart shape. Create a second curve that will be the *Taper Object*, which means the profile of your shape all along its length, the distance of the *Taper Object* curve from its origin will determine the thickness of the profile. Select your heart curve, in the *Object Data* panel, under *Geometry*, select the *Taper Object*, set the *Depth* (thickness) of the object:

[image]

In the same panel, under *Shape*, set the *Resolution* (subdivision) along the length, under *Bevel*, set the *Resolutio*n along the width. You can lower down these resolutions as you'll give a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to your object later.

[image]

Duplicate your heart curve (to keep a copy somewhere) and right click > *Convert To > Mesh*, now your object is a mesh:

[image]

Switch to *Edit* mode, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> for transparency, select all the bottom and <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete Vertices*:

[image]

Select the bottom edge loops and extrude down with <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>:

[image]

Select all, press <kbd>M</kbd> to *Merge by Distance*. Give your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]